# Best way to list 100 first files in a directory sorted by time

Tags: filesystem, ls

What would be the best way to list 100 first files in a directory sorted by the created timestamp (oldest first). The directory is quite large (around 100000 files).

**ls** piped to **head** takes an awful long time to complete.

Edit:

- Filesystem is ext3.
- limiting the number of files in the folder is not worth the effort, since this is going to be a rare "clean-up" operation and files are generated by a 3rd party software.
- Using file *modified time*, instead of the *creation time* provides and acceptable solution.

Comment: If it's a clean-up operation, maybe what you want is just `find -mtime +<number of days> -delete` to clean up all files older than a certain age.  That will mean no sort is necessary.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You say that "**ls** piped to **head** takes an awful long time to complete".

The cause of this is not `ls`, but the number of files in your directory.  If you have 100,000 files in a single directory, any way of solving this problem would have to get information about all 100,000 files before it could even think about sorting them or printing any output.

**If it's taking too long, the real solution is to split the files over multiple directories.**

If you can't spread the files over several directories, *is there any way you can narrow down the number of files to consider*?  e.g. if the file names include a date, maybe you can include a wildcard so the system doesn't have to sort 100,000 files.  Or maybe they're sequentially numbered? (This may or may not help, but is worth trying.)

How many times are you trying to do this?  *Maybe it's worth saving/caching the output for re-use*.

---

Now, a question.

*Are you **sure** you mean "creation time" and not "change time"*?  Most tools can only display "change time", not "creation time".

Getting "creation time" is a very new thing, which requires an ext4 filesystem, and some tools that aren't easy to install.

---

**If you want change time**

Change time (ctime for short) means the time the attributes of the file last changed.

`ls -c` sorts by ctime.

You want the output in ascending order, not descending, so you need to reverse the output with the `-r` option too.

So you could do it like this:

```
ls -cr | head -n 100
```

A longer solution to the same problem using `stat`:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec stat -c $'%Z\t%n' '{}' \; |
    sort -k 1n |
    cut -f 2 -d $'\t' |
    head -n 10 |
    sed -e 's/^\.\///'
```

but that runs slower than `ls -cr` on my system.

---

**If you want modification time**

Modification time (mtime for short) means the time the contents of the file last changed.

`ls -t` sorts by mtime.

Change `ls -cr` to `ls -tr` (best option) or change `stat -c $'%Z\t%n'` to `stat -c $'%Y\t%n'`.

---

**If you need creation time**

(crtime for short)

This is harder.

First, ensure the directory is on a filesystem that is formatted using `ext4`.  You can use `tune2fs -l <device name>` to check this.

Then, there is a new `stat` format called `%W`, which can help you here.  To get it, you'll have to download a version of [GNU Coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) released in October 2010 or after, extract it, compile it, and install it.

Then, depending on your kernel, this *might* work (haven't tried it).

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec stat -c $'%W\t%n' '{}' \; |
    sort -k 1n |
    cut -f 2 -d $'\t' |
    head -n 10 |
    sed -e 's/^\.\///'
```

See also:

- [stat read crtime from ext4](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/qVD1ZF4AdXEHJD4V3zoR)
- [a Ruby script to access crtime on Linux](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/12121)

---

**If you get errors about `"'$\t'`**

The `'$\t'` notation requires `bash` or `zsh`: it will not work in `dash` or `sh` on Ubuntu.  If you really need to use those shells, you will need to change any `\t` to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd> and remove the leading `$` from just before the opening quote.

Comment: It's possible he may not be running ext4.  I run Ubuntu 10.04 on all my machines, but run JFS on several drives.  AFAIK JFS does support creation time stamps.

Comment: Indeed.  We know that it's not supported on ext3 and it is supported on ext4.  A quick search suggests it might work with zfs, or the FreeBSD ufs, but neither of those are common on Ubuntu!  Not sure about jfs or xfs or anything else.  Would be happy to hear more if you can find info/links.

Comment: Thank you for that very comprehensive answer and for the subtle reminder to be write more specific questions ;) "Find" turned out to be a winner performance-wise, fs-type turned out to be ext3.

Answer (score 2):

Another way if found of doing things today might be relevant to your performance issues:

```
I=0; ls -cr /dir/ | while read file; do I=`expr $I + 1`; echo "$file"; if [ $I == 100 ]; then break; fi; done
```

That should in theory start outputting a lot faster but I guess it depends where the lag is coming from. It could just be taking `ls` a long time to sort the files.

Comment: I doubt it.  `head` actually exits as soon as it has read enough input.  Try running both with `time` at the front.  The `head` version is much faster on my system anyway.