# how do I view a file strictly by the date it was accessed/created/downloaded

Tags: updates, files, navigation

I am looking for a command that I can use to locate a file by the date a file was created on my computer

Comment: Does this Q&A help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/23688/best-way-to-list-100-first-files-in-a-directory-sorted-by-time?

Comment: Do I guess correctly that you want to see **only** files with a specific date?

Comment: @guntbert that's correct, specifically by date my man. ^^