# How do I quickly (as quick as possible) list ten files from a very large directory, any files?

Tags: command-line, ls

I have a directory containing 0.5 million text files, and I want to open one or more with vim to check the text pattern. How can I get same ten file names quickly to open as samples? All the file names are unknown.

I've tried `ls directory`, only to find that it's too slow to finish listing all the files. Please don't provide me with answers which need checking time stamps or others like randomly or something else. Here the point is time. As fast as possible.

I get to know from @the_velour_fog that there is a direct solution using vim (:args `find . -type f \| head -n10`, if someone doesn't need to run vim with plugins like nerdtree and etc this method is highly recommended) but please give me a Ubuntu answer.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/23688/best-way-to-list-100-first-files-in-a-directory-sorted-by-time

Comment: I don't require the system to check the time stamp of all the files, which costs time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your main concern is time and you want to list any 10 files, you should look at the `-U` option which means to list entries without sorting.

So you can do:

```
ls -U
```

For 10 files only, *assuming no filenames with newline(s) or any unusual characters*:

```
ls -U | head -10
```

---

A bit better would be to do this only by shell itself:

```
printf '%s\n' *
```

For 10 files:

```
printf '%s\n' * | head -10
```

---

Here is the timing stat on my system for 2000 files on my `zsh`:

```
( ls --color=auto foobar* | head -10; )  0.044 total
( ls --color=auto -U foobar* | head -10; )  0.020 total
( printf '%s\n' foobar* | head -10; )  0.013 total
```

Also note that, some of these might well trigger `ARG_MAX` if you have many files in the directory, in that case use need to use some other ways like `find` or a shell loop.

Answer (score 2):

Try `cd`ing into the directory and opening vim, then once in vim, run this ex command

```
:args `find . -type f \| head -n10`
```

My testing showed that vim itself handled the files with spaces in them

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your meaning. I mean how do I know that the file names in the directory are in the same pattern.

Comment: Do you think `find` will be faster than `ls`? and also why statically setting file names by aliases?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But your answer is kind of not that robust. If some files contain space I'll open those non-existing files.

Comment: @heemayl it doesn't really matter whether find is faster than ls, because [due to the nature of UNIX pipes](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68417/106525) only 10 files get processed, then find exits. however I tested on 2222 files, and it did seem find was slightly faster, also - as you probably know - you should never parse `ls`

Comment: @heemayl statically setting files by alias, its just the first thing I thought of , I tested it on my machine, and it worked, so I posted.

Comment: @lerneradams good point about the spaces, I have updated answer. Im testing on my computer now, but I suspect it should be ok with spaces

Comment: 1. `head` does not take NUL delimited input, so your one will choke on filenames with newlines 2. `ls` can be parsed when you know your input does not contain any control characters or newlines

Comment: Awesome! Since I asked the question in Askubuntu, please write the answe  that I thought is not robust. The drawback of this `:args \`find . -type f \| head -n10\`` is that I should run vim without plugins like nerdtree and etc.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have **mlocate** installed on your computer (if not I recommand you to do so, it's very useful for searching file)

With it installed (and initialized with a first call to the **updatedb** command) you can try something like:

```
locate /path/to/directory | head -n [qty of file wanted]
```

That should work as good as **ls** and will provide you a list of the *n* file asked with there full path